# ¿Cómo eliminar los números de cada sublista en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
[['Italia', 2], ['Turquia', 9], ['Grecia', 7]]
```

Quisiera eliminar los números de cada sub lista, solo usando `remove` o `pop` mediante una iteración y no elemento por elemento.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
lista_1= [['Itália', 2], [9, 'Turquía'], ['Grecia', 7], [100, 'Perú'], [79, 'Hong Kong'], ['Francia', 10], [12, 'México'], ['Bolivia', 7], ['Paraguay', 8]]
lista_1[0].pop(1) 
lista_1[1].pop(0) 
lista_1[2].pop(1) 
lista_1[3].pop(0) 
lista_1[4].pop(0) 
lista_1[5].pop(1) 
lista_1[6].pop(0) 
lista_1[7].pop(1) 
lista_1[8].pop(1)
print("Los nombres de los paises son: ", lista_1)

lista_resultado = [['Italia', 2], ['Turquia', 9]]
for elemento in lista_resultado:
    if elemento[1]:
        lista_resultado.remove(elemento[1])
```

Comment: Buen día, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Es desmotivante entrar en una publicación con la intención de ayudar y ver que el usuario no ha mostrado que ha investigado o intentado algo. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que tienes hasta el momento y los errores que recibes, o en su defecto mostrar lo que has investigado. El objetivo de este sitio es ayudar a las personas que muestran un esfuerzo por resolver sus propias preguntas. Si la solicitud es del tipo alguien hágalo por mi, tal vez un sitio de `freelance` sea mejor opción.

Comment: Te pareces al tipo de profesores de los que me enseñan, que no enseñan nada, si pregunté aquí es por que ya sinceramente no encuentro en ningún lado una respuesta, te muestro todos los intentos que hice, uno me da bien pero trato de hacerlo con una iteración y no me sale

Comment: lista_1=[['Itália', 2], [9, 'Turquía'], ['Grecia', 7], [100, 'Perú'], [79, 'Hong Kong'], ['Francia', 10], [12, 'México'], ['Bolivia', 7], ['Paraguay', 8]]

lista_1[0].pop(1)
lista_1[1].pop(0)
lista_1[2].pop(1)
lista_1[3].pop(0)
lista_1[4].pop(0)
lista_1[5].pop(1)
lista_1[6].pop(0)
lista_1[7].pop(1)
lista_1[8].pop(1)

print("Los nombres de los paises son: ", lista_1)

Comment: lista_resultado=[['Italia', 2], ['Turquia', 9]]
for elemento in lista_resultado:
    if elemento[1]:
     lista_resultado.remove(elemento[1])

Comment: Hola, @agos. Son las políticas del sitio y tiene todo el sentido del mundo. Una pregunta tiene que venir acompañada de una muestra de código, sin más. Nadie está en tu contra ni estamos en contra de enseñar. Editas la pregunta, añades el código y todos estamos para ayudarte :).

Comment: He editado tu pregunta y añadido el código y he solicitado reapertura.

Comment: Hay gente que pregunta sin intentar. Por eso necesitamos pruebas de que te esforzaste.

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```py
lista = [['Italia', 2], ['Turquia', 9], ['Grecia', 7]]

for sublista in lista:
    sublista.remove(sublista[1])

print(lista)
```

Este código itera a través de cada sublista en la lista principal y utiliza el método `remove` para eliminar el segundo elemento de cada sublista, que en este caso es el número. Este enfoque asume que siempre quieres eliminar el segundo elemento de cada sublista.

Comment: Hay muchas gracias!!! estoy muy agradecida :´)

Comment: El código únicamente elimina los elementos con índice 1 de las sub listas, si tuvieras una lista así `lista = [['Italia', 2], ['Turquia', 9], [7, 'Grecia']]` el `7` de la última sub lista no se eliminaría

Comment: Tu código asume también que la primera aparición del elemento está en el indice 1. Pero puede que no siempre sea así.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que requiere uso de remove o pop y de iterar lo haría de esta manera:

```
for lista in lista_1:

    # isinstance devuelve True o False si lista[0] es un entero.
    if isinstance(lista[0], int):
        a.pop(0)
    else:
        a.pop()
```

Pero si no tuviera esas limitaciones lo haría de esta otra forma:

```
# En este caso tenes un bucle for que recorre otro bucle for.
# En el 2do bucle chequeamos si el elemento no es un número entero,
# si no es entero se agrega a la lista de lo contrario no usa el elemento
lis = [elem for lista in lista_1 for elem in lista if not isinstance(e, int)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lista_1= [['Itália', 2], [9, 'Turquía'], ['Grecia', 7], [100, 'Perú'], [79, 'Hong Kong'], ['Francia', 10], [12, 'México'], ['Bolivia', 7], ['Paraguay', 8]]

print(lista_1)
for sublista in lista_1:
    if type(sublista[0]) == int:
        sublista.pop(0)
    else:
        sublista.pop()
print(lista_1)
```

Podés intentar con ese código, por lo que veo, es irregular el sentido en el que estan armadas las sublistas, y lo podés hacer de la siguiente forma. sublista.pop() por si solo lo que hace es eliminar el ultimo elemento del array y devolverlo, pero si le especificas un indice, elimina el mismo y lo devuelve.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Todas las respuestas anteriores asumen que tu lista contiene únicamente sub listas, lo cual no especificas en tu pregunta.

Podría haber casos donde los elementos de la lista principal fueran otro tipo de valor pero aún así se deseara quitar los enteros.

También podría haber casos en los que las sub listas contengan sub listas.

Podrías revisar si cada elemento de la lista principal es una sub lista, en ese caso, volver a llamar la función para quitar todos los enteros (Recursión) sin importar donde se encuentren.

Ejemplo:

**Nota:** Agregé algunos elementos a `lista_1`

```
lista_1= [['Itália', 2], [9, 'Turquía'], ['Grecia', 7], [100, 'Perú'], [79, 'Hong Kong'], ['Francia', 10], [12, 'México'], ['Bolivia', 7], ['Paraguay', 8], 'prueba', 8, ['sub lista', ['sub lista de la sub lista', 3, 4], 2]]

# Función para quitar enteros
def quitar_int(lista):
    # Inicializar el iterador
    i = 0
    # Recorrer la lista
    while i < len(lista):
        # Obtener el elemento actual de la lista
        elemento = lista[i]
        # Revisar si el elemento es una sub lista
        if isinstance(elemento, list):
            # Volver a llamar quitar_int() con la sub lista
            quitar_int(elemento)
        # Revisar si el elemento es un entero
        if isinstance(elemento, int):
            # Quitar el entero de la lista
            lista.pop(i)
        else:
            # Incrementar el iterador
            i += 1

print(f'Lista original: {lista_1}')
quitar_int(lista_1)
print(f'Lista sin `int`: {lista_1}')
```

Esto imprime:

```
Lista original: [['Itália', 2], [9, 'Turquía'], ['Grecia', 7], [100, 'Perú'], [79, 'Hong Kong'], ['Francia', 10], [12, 'México'], ['Bolivia', 7], ['Paraguay', 8], 'prueba', 8, ['sub lista', ['sub lista de la sub lista', 3, 4], 2]]
Lista sin `int`: [['Itália'], ['Turquía'], ['Grecia'], ['Perú'], ['Hong Kong'], ['Francia'], ['México'], ['Bolivia'], ['Paraguay'], 'prueba', ['sub lista', ['sub lista de la sub lista']]]
```